# How Ignore ToDo in specific folder or file with Intellij Idea IDE

Tags: intellij-idea, todo

i'm using jquery sourcecode for development (later i'm gonna change for min, version) and Intellij Idea detect the TODO in the jquery code, anybody know how ignore the todo in an specific file or folder?

Comment: probably you should mark this directory as library, not as sourcecode directory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PhpStorm Ignore files/directories in TODO feature](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14901462/phpstorm-ignore-files-directories-in-todo-feature)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[image]

todo->scope Based. 
   use [...] button config your filter patterns

every button click once  and then your will know

Answer (score 29):

This is how I did this with Pycharm. Right click on the folder you wish to exclude, then Mark Directory as > Excluded.

[image: Pycharm Menu]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19916237)

Comment: Hello Austin - Thanks for embedding the image for me - I am not allowed due to low reputation (This is my first answer) - your downvote is just going to exacerbate this situation

Comment: I didn't edit the post nor downvote you. Though, I did mark the post for deletion because you should've included the important parts from whatever the link was into the post itself

Comment: Should be the default answer )))